# javascript: window.location automatically changed included links

Tags: javascript, html

I've used window.location (.assign, .replace, .href) to redirect to a page product on click. But for some reason it automatically changes some of href links.

For example: 
previous href="commercial/fonts/fonts.min.css" is now href="product/commercial/fonts/fonts.min.css".

*previous HTML file*

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="commercial/fonts/fonts.min.css" />
```

*After this click event triggers*

```
$('.productImage').on('click', function(){
        var product_id = $(this).data('id');
        window.location.assign("/product/"+product_id);
});
```

*New HTML*

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="product/commercial/fonts/fonts.min.css" />
```

*Product is automatically to the href. This happens with some other files as well. In case of img src as well*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `/` at the beginning of your href, like so: `href="commercial/fonts/fonts.min.css"` - that should make the URL relative to your document root. At the moment you're using a URL that is relative to the current document. You may want to read up on absolute vs relative URLs, eg in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21828923/1983827).